# ¿ Diccionario o Tupla ? ¿Como acceder a una key dentro de otra key en Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Tengo un web service en el que con la libreria Alamo recojo unos datos.
El resultado lo tengo en una variable tal como : response.result.value
Dentro de esta variable quiero acceder a una key de segundo nivel.

El resultado lo devuelvo como:

```
response.result.value as! NSDictionary
```

También he probado como:

```
response.result.value as! [String:Any]
```

En otra función lo recojo y accedo a la primera key como:

```
result?["key1"]
```

Hasta hay todo bien, ahora intento acceder a otra key que esta en el siguiente nivel:

```
result?["key1"]["key2"]
```

Aqui ya me tira error.

¿ Como puedo acceder al siguiente nivel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede asignar el primer nivel a una variable, por ejemplo:

```
let abc = [
"key1": 1,
"key2": [
    "a": 22,
    "b": 33
  ]
] as [String : Any]

print(abc["key1"]) // 1

let res = abc["key2"] as! [String: Any]

print(res["a"]) // 22
```

Comment: ¿ Como lo puedo concatenar en una sola linea, llamando a las 2 keys ? En mi caso no me funciona tengo que hacer la primera llamada de esta manera: result?["key1"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] y al intentar la segunda llamada ya me tira error con: (result?["key1"] as? [[String:AnyObject]])["key2"]

Comment: que tal si remueves un [ ], asi:  result?["key1"] as? [String:AnyObject]